# Developing on Windows using Eclipse?

Tags: ros, ide

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish I could develop ROS on an IDE like Eclipse on Windows. However I did not found any reference to install on windows.

Does that work??? because it would be much more practical than having to use a Virtual Machine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268994/developing-on-windows-using-eclipse?????/) by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
What version of Windows?

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-16**:
windows 10 on my desktop and windows 7 on my notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are some instructions on how to get ROS working on Windows 10. It won't work on Windows 7 because Windows 7 doesn't have the ability to run linux binaries natively which Windows 10 can (mostly from what I know). This will require you to do a manual patch to `ros_comm`.

http://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows (from http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows)

You can use Eclipse on Ubuntu from what I know if that's all that you're looking for.

---

**Edit:**

As @gvdhoorn pointed out in the comments, there are issues with using ROS on Windows. Here's the admonition that was referred to:

> Note that this is not a native
> installation of ROS Lunar on Windows,
> but the Ubuntu version of ROS Lunar
> running on-top of the Windows [Subsystem for Linux (WSL).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)
>
> Support for GUI tools is limited (fi:
> all 3D rendering is software based)
> and needs additional software on the
> Windows side (X server), access to
> hardware is currently not or only
> minimally possible (a WSL limitation)
> and Windows file system performance is
> not on-par with a Linux system which
> has an impact on IO-bottlenecked
> tasks.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-16**:
Does it work for ROS Kinetic?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
According to [this comment](http://disq.us/p/1kxb2t7) from the instructions, it was only tested on Lunar. The person that this comment was replying to was trying with Kinetic but wasn't having much luck.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-08-16**:
My goal is to write the code in windows, copy all the files like the directory with src, makefile, package.xml, launch, then paste on my device running Ubuntu and install like I do with everything else, just like github.
Have you tested before doing the same?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
No. I actually prefer using Ubuntu. Windows (for me) tends to makes development less straightforward than Ubuntu.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-17**:
@renanmb: please take note of the admonition on the [wiki/Installation/Windows](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) page that @jayess linked.

ROS on Win10 on WSL is far from a native installation of ROS on Windows, so expect some bumpiness.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-09-23**:
It is true. Windows does not work very well. Virtual Machine works fine for most of the time.